# Installing correct ethernet controller driver on Windows 10 Pro

Tags: windows, dell, drivers

I cloned a PC and it turned out to be a different model so many of the drivers need to be reinstalled without internet access. Currently trying to get the Ethernet Controller device driver installed. My system info:

- Model: Dell OptiPlex 7060
- Type: x64
- Processor: Intel Core i7-8700
- BaseBoard Manufacturer: Dell Inc

Searching Dell's "Drivers & Downloads" page [I'm presented with two options when I search for "ethernet"](https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/optiplex-7060-desktop/drivers):

1. Aquantia 5G Network Addin Card Windows x64 Driver
2. Intel I2xx/825xx Gigabit Ethernet Network Controller Driver

How can I determine which of these (if either) I need?

I am new-ish to the Windows operating system. Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download and install the "Gigabit Ethernet" one for your network card.

"Aquantia 5G Network" is a 5G (LTE) device and may be useful for WAN (Internet) connectivity, but "Intel Gigabit" is definately a physical network interface.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this now. Are there any possible consequences to prepare for if it happens to be the wrong driver? Or are you actually certain that will work out?

Comment: If it's the wrong one, just nothing will happen.

Comment: Thank you, that was it. I still have no internet but for other reasons, the ethernet driver is correctly installed now.

Comment: Aquantia does indeed make [2.5G, 5G and 10G NICs](https://www.aquantia.com/products/aqtion-nics/). This doesn't sound like a WWAN card.